# Can an uncountable metric space have a concentrated point?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, and define a *concentrated point* (if one exists) to be $x \in M$ such that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, the set $M \setminus D_{\varepsilon}(x) $ is finite.

For example, consider $M = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, with the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $0
$ is a concentrated point of $M$.

**Question(s)**:

1. If $M$ is uncountable, can it have a concentrated point?
2. If not, relax the definition of concentration point so that we only need $M \setminus D_{\varepsilon}(x) $ to be countable. Can $M$ now have a concentrated point?

---

Here are some simple observations.

- if $M$ has a concentrated point, it is compact
- any concentrated point of $x \in M$ is unique; indeed, every sequence in $M$ must converge to $x$
- correspondingly, if $M \leq N$, $M$ is closed in $N$

---

Here are two slightly less trivial observations:

**Proposition:** If $M$ satisfies (1), $M$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof sketch**: Given a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, say that $S$ is *almost-Darboux** if $\forall a, b \in S$, $a<b$, $\exists c \in S$ such that $a < c < b$.

**Lemma**: any uncountable subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has a subset $T \subseteq S$ which is almost-Darboux.

Hence, $M$ has a subset which is almost-Darboux. It follows that we cannot have a point $x$ with $M \setminus D_{\varepsilon}(x)$ finite $\forall \varepsilon > 0$. $\square$

*This seems like quite a fundamental property that I've encountered a few times now, but I don't know its actual name.

---

**Corollary**: If $M$ satisfies (1), $M$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof**: Consider $M\cap \partial D_{\varepsilon}(x)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Clearly, this must be finite. Hence, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is effectively the same as $\mathbb{R}$ for our purposes. Result follows. $\square$

---

Intuitively, I do not expect either (1) or (2) to be true, because uncountable sets are "much larger" than countable sets. At the least, I suspect that any metric space satisfying (1) or even (2) to be highly pathological.

Please let me know if anything is not clear. My proofs may not be correct; the sketches contain all that I used to justify the statements to myself only on an intuitive level.

Comment: Ad (1): $M = \{x\}\cup \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} M\setminus D_{1/n}(x)$ which is a countable union of finite sets, so $M$ is countable.

Comment: @psl2Z This should be an official answer. You can easily generalize it to the relaxed variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in M$. For $n>0$, let $M_n = M \setminus B(x,\frac{1}{n})$. Then $M\setminus \{x\} = \cup_{n\geqslant 1} M_n$. Therefore:

1. If for all $n$, $M_n$ is finite, then $M\setminus \{x\}$ is a countable union of finite sets, and then is countable. It follows that so is $M$.
2. The same argument shows that if $M_n$ is countable for any $n$, then $M$ is countable.